# ActiveX support in IE10 on windows 8

Tags: activex

Is ActiveX support is available in IE-10 on windows 8 . Because ActiveX is not working on IE-10. I did find the problem i had done all the settings  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved the problem by doing Following steps.

-Following Registry entry should be Added in order to run ActiveX on Windows 8 64 bit.

```
 1. open Regedit .  
 2.Path: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework
 3. Add a new DWORD 32 bit value
 4. Set its name “EnableIEHosting”
 5. Set its value “1”.
```

Answer (score 0):

ActiveX works fine on IE10 in windows 8, as long as you aren't in Metro / Windows RT mode.  You can only use activex controls in desktop mode.

(our plugin works fine; https://downloads.gradecam.com)